# Removing duplicates from JOIN between two tables (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to join two tables called MSISDN and RANGES.
Example:

```
MSISDN table:

MSISDN          NETWORK
110011500   D000
110211501   D000

RANGES table:

PREFIX  NETWORK DESCRIPTION
11  D000    NEOTEL
1102    D000    TELKOM
```

I’m joining as:

```
select * 
from MSISDN a 
  left join RANGES b 
    on  a.msisdn like b. prefix || '%' 
    and a.network = b.network;
```

This query will give me duplicates in case as for MSISDN ‘110211501’, because it will match with both prefixes.
I need to avoid these duplicates. I need to only have the match with the longest prefix (in this case ‘1102’).
Is there any way how to join avoiding the duplicates or doing de duplication afterwards?

Comment: What you really need is a better data model, without the ambiguous compound values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        n.*, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY n.MSISDN ORDER BY length(n.prefix) DESC) as rnk
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM MSISDN a 
        LEFT JOIN RANGES b 
             ON a.msisdn like b. prefix || '%' and a.network = b.network 
        ) n 
    )t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

it should remove the duplicates and give you the records with longer prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
     , MAX(LENGTH(b.prefix)) AS prefix_length
from MSISDN a 
  left join RANGES b 
    on  a.msisdn like b. prefix || '%' 
    and a.network = b.network
GROUP BY a.msisdn
       , a.network
```

Comment: This will work if I want to retrieved MSISDN and NETWORK only, not all   other columns (beacuse of the group by MSISDN and NETWORK)

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap this in a subquery and join to `Ranges`.